# Get the selection of radiobuttons to populate MSSQL table depending on which button is clicked

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter

I am trying to get the selection of two radio buttons clicked. If the top button is clicked, it should give the string value I assigned to a variable. If the second button is pressed it should get the text in the text box. I am trying to get the selections in the submit definition.
Here is the code I have written.

```
    ## ---- Section 3 sub-frame 1
    
    self.section3_1 = Frame(self.section3)

    self.L5 = Label(self.section3_1, text = "Urlaubsgrund")
    self.L5.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.Rvar1 = IntVar()

    self.R1 = Radiobutton(self.section3_1, text = "Erholungsurlaub", variable = self.Rvar1, value = 1)
    self.R2 = Radiobutton(self.section3_1, text = "Sonderurlaub aufgrund von", variable = self.Rvar1, value = 2)

    self.R1.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.R2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.section3_1.pack(padx = 50, pady = 5, side = LEFT)
    
    ## ---- Section 3 sub-frame 1


    ## ---- Section 3 sub-frame 2
    self.section3_2 = Frame(self.section3)
    
    self.L6 = Label(self.section3_2, text = "Falls Sonderurlaub gewählt, Begründung angeben")
    self.L6.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.T1 = Text(self.section3_2, height = 2, width = 20)
    self.T1.pack(padx =5, pady = 5, expand = True, fill = X)


    self.section3_2.pack(padx = 50, pady = 5, side = RIGHT)

     ## ---- Section 3 sub-frame 2

    self.section3.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, expand = True, fill = X)
   
    # ----- Section 3
    
    self.B0 = Button(self.Main, text = "Submit", command = lambda : [self.submit(), self.click_me()])
    self.B0.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, side = RIGHT)

    self.Main.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, expand = True, fill = X)


def submit(self):
    try:
        self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                "Server=SOPCP01DE;"
                                "Database=PulseCoreTest5;"
                                "UID=PCDev2;"
                                "PWD=PCCSDev2PC5_!")
        self.cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()
        print("Connection Succeeded")
    except:
        print("Connection Failed")

    start_date = self.dDateStart.get().strip()
    end_date = self.dDateEnd.get().strip()
    if start_date or end_date:
        if end_date == '':
            end_date = start_date
    
    erholungsurlaub = self.R1.get() and 'Erholungsurlaub'
    sonderurlaub = self.R2.get() and self.T1.get("1.0", "end")
    gruende = erholungsurlaub = sonderurlaub
    if value == 1:
        return erholungsurlaub

    elif value == 2:
        return sonderurlaub
    else:
        return 'Erhonlungsurlaub'
    
        sql = """INSERT INTO dbo.PC_VacationsRequests (dDateStart, dDateEnd, nEmployee, sReasons, sStatus, sStellvertreter)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""
        values = (start_date, end_date, self.nEmployee.get(), gruende, "geplant", self.E4.get())
    
        self.cursor.execute(sql, values)
        self.cnxn.commit() 
        self.cnxn.close()
```

Comment: Your code is not a [mre] and there are few issues: why `gruende = erholungsurlaub = sonderurlaub`? `value` is undefined in `if value == 1`, etc.

Comment: I am trying to populate one column with either the selection of the first button or the second button. I'm not sure how to do this so I tried to see if I created a variable that was equal to the other two variables to make sure it would only provide one value.